# How to limit number of results of FINDSTR and FIND search on the command line?

Tags: search, find, limit, findstr

Can someone tell me how to limit the number of results of a FINDSTR and FIND search? I'm searching for strings in thousands of files at once and need to limit my results to 500 hits (lines) or so.

I’m on Windows 8.1, 64-bit.